# Why is GNU make ignoring or changing my g++ option (in command part)?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, enums, makefile

I am using the `-std=c++0x` option when compiling my C++ code with g++ 4.4.7 because there are some code like:

```
typedef enum Qualifier {AUTO, CONST, REG, STATIC, VOLATILE} Qualifier;
...
Qualifier q = Qualifier::AUTO;
```

I can use g++ with this option to compile my source files. But when I put the g++ command in my makefile, it didn't work! The GNU make just ignores this option when executing g++ command (it also ignores the output folder of the .o files and put them in current folder) !

My GNU make's version is 3.81 and a part of my makefile is :

```
VPATH = src:obj

all : CCompiler 

CCompiler : main.o  CodeGenerator.o  FileWraper.o  ir.tab.o \
            lex.ir.o  lex.yy.o  Symbol.o  SymbolTable.o  yacc.tab.o
    g++ -std=c++0x -o bin/CCompiler  obj/*.o

    main.o : src/main.cpp \
        src/FileWraper.h  src/Log.h  src/SymbolTable.h  src/Symbol.h  src/CodeGenerator.h
        g++ -std=c++0x -c -o ./obj/main.o src/main.cpp

    CodeGenerator.o : src/CodeGenerator.cpp \
        src/CodeGenerator.h  src/Symbol.h  src/SymbolTable.h
        g++ -std=c++0x -c -o ./obj/CodeGenerator.o src/CodeGenerator.cpp
```

My project directory is organized like this:

```
    CCompiler/
        Makefile
        src/
        bin/
        obj/
```

And when I executed make, the shell showed this to me:

```
[root@cn CCompiler]$  make
g++    -c -o main.o src/main.cpp
In file included from src/SymbolTable.h:6,
                 from src/main.cpp:4:
src/Symbol.h:112: error: ‘Qualifier’ is not a class or namespace
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Why it happened like this and how could I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try changing the `-std=c++0x` to `-std=c++11`. This has caused problems for me before.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you've specified a rule for `main.o`, not `obj/main.o`.  Likewise, your dependence is on `main.o`, not `obj/main.o`.  You should consider writing a pattern rule for `obj/%.o: src/%.c`.  Specify your object-specific dependencies separately.  Also consider splitting your C++ compiler flags out to a `CXXFLAGS` variable.

Comment: @KepaniHaole Thanks~ But it shows the same content after changing 0x to 11 ...

Comment: @JoeZ Thanks for your advise, I will have a try. Hope it will solve the problem about the output directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `enum class Qualifier { ... }`. Also, the typedef is redundant in C++.

Without the `enum class`, the enumerators will be available as `AUTO` (i.e., without the `Qualifier::` prefix).